# Does convergence for increasing sequences of projections imply convergence for all sequences of projections?

Tags: sequences-and-series, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection, projection-matrices

Let be $\{P_n\}_n$ an increasing sequence ($P_{n+1} \ge P_n$)  of finite dimensional projection operators on a separable Hilbert space $H$. Let $f:H \to \mathbb{C}$. Let us fix $f_n(x):=f(P_nx)$. If $f_n$ converges to $\tilde{f}$ for any **increasing** sequence such that $P_n \to I$ strongly (with $I$ identity operator), is it true that $f_n$ converges to $\tilde f$ for **any** sequence $\{ P_n\}_n$ such that $P_n \to I$ strongly?

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand. You assume that $f_n$ converges for any sequence $P_n$ and then you ask whether $f_n$ converges for any sequence $P_n$. Isn't that exactly the same?

Comment: For any *increasing* at first, then for any.

Comment: I got it now, sorry. Given the arbitrary sequence $P_n$, have you tried considering $Q_n:= \max ( P_1, \ldots, P_n)$? I don't know if the max exists for projections, probably not, but I hope the idea is clear; given an arbitrary, maybe oscillating, sequence, remove oscillations by taking only the biggest element so far.

Comment: Ok, but in this case we would have a convergent increasing subsequence, however my question is, in other words, if $f_n$ does not converge for a  sequence (which is non increasing) could I get some contraddiction with the fact that any increasing sequence converges? I think that in this countable case, the problem concerns only the order but I'm not sure.

Comment: What does $f(x)|_{P_n H}$ mean (as $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}$). Or do you mean $f_n = f|_{P_n H}$? But then, $f_n$ is not defined on the whole $H$?

Comment: @AndreiKh You're right! Now I edit the post, I meant $f(P_nx)$, with $x \in H$.